# iText 7 - Image in Cell of Table fill full height

Tags: java, itext7

I add images in my cells of a table, but it doesn't fit the whole height.

The height is not fixed and can change between 2 rows.

How can my images fit the full height of my cells ?

Here is my problem :
[image]

Here is the code of creation of my table :

```
int nbColumns = 7 + planning.size() *4;
Table table = new Table(nbColumns);
table.setWidthPercent(100);
table.addCell(createCell(""));
table.addCell(createCell("Col1"));
table.addCell(createCell("Col2"));
DateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH", Locale.FRENCH);
for(Date hourDate : planning){
    table.addCell(new Cell(1,4).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(hourFormat.format(hourDate)).setFont(regular).setFontSize(10));
}

table.addCell(createCell("Long"));
table.addCell(createCell("A"));
table.addCell(createCell("B"));
table.addCell(createCell(""));
```

Here is how I add my images for each cell :

```
String IMG = // my img path
table.addCell(createImageCell(IMG));

public static Cell createImageCell(String path) throws MalformedURLException {
            Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(path));
            Cell cell = new Cell().add(img.setMargins(0,0,0,0).setAutoScaleHeight(true).setAutoScale(true)).setPadding(0);
            cell.setBorder(null);
            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm, hmmm, might actually be a bug, looking at the src-code for `setAutoScaleHeight` and it sets the `AUTO_SCALE_WIDTH` - property, not height. I'll see if I can recreate the issue on my end.

Comment: How can I bypass this ? Do you have any trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer for the sake of visibility.

With regards to autoscaling:

- `setAutoScaleHeight()` is currently bugged in iText7 on the develop branch (so the bug will be present in 7.0.5 and prior versions). It currently sets the `AUTO_SCALE_WIDTH`(probably due to a copy-paste oversight), unless the `AUTO_SCALE_WIDTH`property is already set, then it will put them both on false and set the `AUTO_SCALE` to true.
- Fixing the typo does not result in expected behaviour, since we're now aware of the issue, a ticket for it has been added to our backlog.
- Bi-directional autoscaling (via the `AUTO_SCALE`-property) works correctly, but will scale uniformly and thus only scale to width in these case where the cell is greater in height than width.

As for a temporary solutions or trick to bypass it, I don't have a generic one :( for now, apart from waiting for the fix.

I did a quick test with relative height declarations (which should be included in 7.0.5), but that scaled the image uniformly again. Some trial&error and `Image.scaleAbsolute()` can get a desired result but that's hardly automate-able. You could in theory hook into the layout-process by writing your own custom CellRenderer, extracting the height of the largest Cell in to row to use in conjuction with `scaleAbsolute()`, but you're kinda writing the auto-scaling logic yourself at that point.

Some remarks on the OP's posted code as well, in the interest of spreading good practice:

```
int nbColumns = 7 + planning.size() *4;
Table table = new Table(nbColumns);
```

The constructor Table(int) is deprecated (since 7.0.2) and can lead to unexpected behaviour in later versions (this was done when improving the table-layouting mechanisms). It's better to pass a `UnitValue[]`, preferably created using `UnitValue.createPercentArray(float[])` or `UnitValue.createPercentArray(float[])`

```
img.setMargins(0,0,0,0).setAutoScaleHeight(true).setAutoScale(true))
```

`setAutoScale` after `setAutoScaleHeight` makes the latter redundant.

Comment: Ok, so if I sum up, my real solution is to wait for the release 7.0.5. Do you know the release date of it ? 
Or should I go back on the version 5 maybe ? 
Ok, thank you for your correction about new Table(), i will modify it to match the new one.
Yes for the autoscale, i suspected it was useless but i tried everything x)

Comment: It's not going to be fixed in 7.0.5 (release commits have been picked already, before this question was posed). Version after 7.0.5 at the earliest. Though, if you do kinda know what the height of the cells will be (in the posted example, you kinda know if the hours in the cells always have the same pattern), you can scale the image beforehand to fit better.

Comment: Oh ok :( 
But that's the point , height is not always the same :/ 
There is no way to repeat the image ? 
Or is it possible to do it with version 5 ?